# ProFTPd mod_sftp mod_sftp_sql

Tags: mysql, ftp, password, sftp, proftpd

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04
I have setup a ProFTPd service with SSL/TLS, virtual users stored in a MySQL database and quota (mod_tls, mod_sql, mod_sql_mysql, mod_quotatab, mod_quotatab_sql).
It works fine.

I want now to setup the same thing over SFTP instead of SSL/TLS.
I have built ProFTPd from sources with mod_sftp and mod_sftp_sql.

Is it possible to authenticate users with passwords over SFTP/SQL ?

I seen the directive `SFTPAuthMethods` that accepts `password`.
How to bind this with mod_sftp_sql and an SQL query ?
All found documentation is about public key authentication method.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you figure this out? I don't want to use public keys, I want sftp to auth against the same usernames/passwords in my MySQL table that FTPes authenticates with.

Comment: oh, I didn't have my sql auth stuff in <Global> so it wasn't applying to my sftp virtualhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys, SFTPAuthorizedHostKeys and SQLNamedQuery are the parameters you are looking for, I guess.

There is good explanation at the mod_sftp_sql modules documentation page:

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp_sql.html